# python list using inputs

Tags: python, list, input, range

i am making a pizza ordering system for a project, the user chooses how many pizzas they want with this:

```
pizza_number=0
goodpizza_number=False 
while not goodpizza_number:
    try:
        pizza_number= int(input("How many Pizzas do you want? (MAX 5): "))
        if pizza_number ==0 or pizza_number > 5:
            print("Not a correct choice, Try again")
        else:
            goodpizza_number=True 
    except ValueError:
        print("Not a number, Try again")
```

and then there is a list of pizzas for the user:

```
PIZZA_LIST=["Tandoori chicken: $8.50", "Prawn: $8.50", "Ham and cheese: $8.50", "Pepperoni: $8.50", "Hawaiian: $8.50","Beef and onion: $8.50","Meat lovers: $8.50", "Satay chicken: $13.50", "Apricot chicken: $13.50", "Supreme cheese:13.50", "Italian beef: $13.50", "Mediterraneo: $13.50"]
for index in range(0, len(PIZZA_LIST)):
    print(index, PIZZA_LIST[index])
```

and the user is able to choose what pizzas they want with this:

```
pizza=[] 
for n in range(pizza_number): #covers values from 0 to 9 
    pizza = pizza + [int(input("Choose a pizza: "))] 
print(pizza)
```

The first 7 pizzas on the list have to be $8.50 and the last 5 pizzas on the list have to be  $13.50. how can i add the user's choices together and get the prices of all the pizzas they chose and add to the total cost?

Comment: Store the pizzas in a dict like `{"tandoori chichen": 8.50, ...}` that way you can easily look up what price belongs to what pizza and for the total you simply have to add them up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you might want to change how the pizza names and prices are presented. Since you get user input as integer, I would suggest using list of tuples:

```
pizzas_with_prices = [('Tandoori chicken', 8.5), ('Prawn', 8.5) ..., ('Mediterraneo', 13.5)]
```

then you can loop over your `pizza` list (which could be better named as `selected_pizzas` or so):

```
total_price = 0
for selected in selected_pizzas:
  total_price += pizzas_with_prices[selected][1]
print total_price
```

**Also**, couple of suggestions to improve the code:

For the first code block, you can get rid of the `goodpizza_number`

```
number_of_pizzas = 0
while 0 < number_of_pizzas <= 5:
  try:
    number_of_pizzas = int(input("How many Pizzas do you want? (MAX 5): "))
  except ValueError:
    print("Not a number, try again")
```

On the second block, as suggested, you could use list of tuples and use `enumerate`

```
pizzas_with_prices = [('Tandoori chicken', 8.5), ('Prawn', 8.5) ..., ('Mediterraneo', 13.5)]
for index, pizza in enumerate(pizzas_with_prices):
  print("%d %s: $%s" % (index, pizza[0], pizza[1]))
```

Comment: This works great, how i would make it so it only displays the final cost because it is displaying each cost like this:
`How many Pizzas do you want? (MAX 5): 5
0 Tandoori chicken: $8.50
1 Prawn: $8.50
2 Ham and cheese: $8.50
3 Pepperoni: $8.50
4 Hawaiian: $8.50
5 Beef and onion: $8.50
6 Meat lovers: $8.50
7 Satay chicken: $13.50
8 Apricot chicken: $13.50
9 Supreme cheese:13.50
10 Italian beef: $13.50
11 Mediterraneo: $13.50
Choose a pizza: 1
Choose a pizza: 3
Choose a pizza: 5
Choose a pizza: 6
Choose a pizza: 7
8.5
17.0
25.5
34.0
47.5
How would i make it only display 47.5?`

Comment: Do you have the `print total_price` inside the for loop? It should be outside.

Comment: oh you are right i had indented the print. thank you! also do you think you could briefly explain what these lines are doing, so i get a better understanding? Thanks
`for selected in selected_pizzas:
  total_price += pizzas_with_prices[selected][1]`

Comment: Sure. In `selected_pizzas` we have stored all user selections as integers. So in your example in the comment, it would be `[1, 3, 5, 6, 7]`.

Then we loop over that, storing every item in to a variable `selected` for each round.

From `pizzas_with_prices`, we then pick the right pizza based on the index (`pizzas_with_prices[selected]`) which returns a tuple in form of `('name', price)` so we selected the second item, the price (`pizzas_with_prices[selected][1]`).

Finally we add that price to the `total_price`. 

Hope that helps.

Comment: If you like the answer, consider giving it a vote in addition to just accepting it as an answer! Thanks.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to do so, sorry. I am very new to stack overflow and i have to have 15 rep to upvote

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another pizza name and pizza price in a dict. The user choice of pizza can be put in a list. Once you have the list, iterate over the list to get price from pizza name-price dict and add then to get total price.

Answer (score 0):

```
total_cost = sum([float(PIZZA_LIST[idx].split('$')[1]) for idx in pizza])
```

By the way: you can replace

```
pizza = pizza + [int(input("Choose a pizza: "))]
```

with

```
pizza.append(int(input("Choose a pizza: ")))
```